# Looking for EpiServer Documentation

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I discovered EpiServer forum [World.EpiServer](http://world.episerver.com/) but as for me its very poor for understanding. Is there any blog for EpiServer Commerce. For example with creating model of entrie , types of categories and nodes and than creating one catalog with some products (one or more) and in the end ... displaying this one product on page ?  With normall documentation how to bid product to page and etc. So can some body recomend some blog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there isn't a dedicated blog for EPiServer Commerce and there isn't anything like [Joel Abrahamsson](http://joelabrahamsson.com/)'s blog for EPi Commerce.

You can of course find some material on EPi World, but I've always found that platform difficult to use as well.

Other than that, Svein Aandahl has a few blog articles here [http://sveinaandahl.blogspot.nl/](http://sveinaandahl.blogspot.nl/2014/04/how-to-connect-pim-system-to-episerver.html).